# msiexec with -Wait installation continuously failing

Tags: powershell, silent-installer

There is my script:

```
try {
    Start-Process "C:\tmp\_deployment\AcroRdrDC1900820071_hu_HU.exe" -argumentlist '/sALL /EULA_ACCEPT=YES /qn"' -PassThru -Wait
} catch {
    Write-Host "mypatch.exe returned the following error $_"
    Throw "Aborted mypatch.exe returned $_"
}

try {
    Start-Process "C:\tmp\_deployment\Office 2016 Prof Plus 64bit HUN\setup.exe" -Verb runAs -PassThru -Wait
} catch {
    Write-Host "mypatch.exe returned the following error $_"
    Throw "Aborted mypatch.exe returned $_"
}

try {
    Start-Process "C:\tmp\_deployment\jre-8u181-windows-x64.exe" -ArgumentList '/s INSTALL_SILENT=1 STATIC=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_JAVA=1 WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL=H WEB_ANALYTICS=0 EULA=0 REBOOT=0 NOSTARTMENU=0 SPONSORS=0' -PassThru -Wait
} catch {
    Write-Host "mypatch.exe returned the following error $_"
    Throw "Aborted mypatch.exe returned $_"
}

Start-Process msiexec.exe -PassThru -Wait -ArgumentList '/I C:\tmp\_deployment\7z1805-x64.msi /passive'


Start-Process msiexec.exe -PassThru -Wait -ArgumentList '/I C:\tmp\_deployment\tightvnc-2.8.11-gpl-setup-64bit.msi /quiet /norestart'
```

Everything is fine until the 7zip installation is complete. When it's done the next process - tightvnc - not installing to the computer.Everything is fine until the 7zip installation finishes. When the next process - tightvnc - starts, the installation will exit immediately and tightvnc not available on the machine.

I tried to change the last lines with this:

```
 msiexec.exe /I C:\tmp\_deployment\tightvnc-2.8.11-gpl-setup-64bit.msi /quiet /norestart -Wait
```

But nothing.
If I run the the last lines alone, tightnc install will be successful.

I think the -Wait parameters not working. Any idea how can I solve this? 
If anyone knows how to simplify this script, I would appreciate it!
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try installing the msi files using the `/LV` option to have it write a log. In this log there may be clues for you to see what goes wrong [Msiexec.exe Command Line](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html)

Comment: I'd recommend `/l*v`, but yes.